# Layout in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout

I used to make my own layout for managing loading pages inside the index page

```
   <div id="content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'visits', 'controller' => 'visit', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => 'view'), NULL, TRUE); ?>" class="showVisists">Display all visits</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'visits', 'controller' => 'visit', 'action' => 'index', 'page' => 'add'), NULL, TRUE); ?>" class="addVisit">Add new visit</a></li>
            </ul>

            <span class="result"><?php echo $this->message ?></span>
            <div id="innerpage">
             <?php include_once($this->pageToInclude . ".phtml") ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I choose an anchor from the navigation, the parameter is received through the controller index action, which chooses the page I have to include and returns it to the index page so the page can be viewed.

```
public function indexAction() {
    $status = $this->getRequest()->getParam('page');
    switch ($status) {
        case 'view':
            $pageToInclude = 'get-visits';
            break;
        case 'add':
            $pageToInclude = 'add';
            break;
   default:
            $pageToInclude = 'get-visits';

    }

    $this->view->pageToInclude = $pageToInclude;
}
```

Now I want to use the layouts that are supported by Zend framework.

I enabled the layout and copied all the stuff in index to layout.phtml.

When I included pages inside the layout an error occurred. I know that I shouldn't use `includes` or even `require` in Zend framework, but I don't know how to show the view of "get all visits" when I click on the anchor "Display all visits" inside the layout page.

I want to make something like this:

```
<div id="innerpage">
               <?php echo $this->layout()->content; ?>

            </div>
```

but how should I specify the content dynamically?

Note: I am new to Zend framework, and not yet familiar on how to work with it effectively.

Comment: please run throught the [Zend Framework Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html) and [Rob Allen's ZF 1.11 Tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/). Get a little comfortable with layouts. then look into Zend_View helpers, a view helper is likely your best solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum your question is not 100% Clear. Is it AJAX based?

NON Ajax Based:

Just link from the Navigation to your Controller Action, than the corresponding ".phtml" View is redered in "content area":

```
// reders: view/scripts/index/addvisit.phtml
public function addvisitAction 
{

}
```

Best way to build your links inside the navigation ist the "url" Helper:

```
<?php

$linkToAllVisits = $this->url(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'addvisits',
    'module'     => 'default'
));

?>

<div id="navi">
    <li><a href="<?php echo $linkToAllVisits; ?>">AllVisits</a></li>
</div>
```

If you want to load the content with an ajaxRequest (i think you want to do this) just open the same controller action like in the sample above but disable the layout for this action:

```
// reders: view/scripts/index/addvisit.phtml
public function addvisitAction 
{
    // disable layout and return only .phtml
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();

}
```

by the way, if you want to use Actionnames with "-" you have to name the Actions like this in CamelCase:

```
// add-visits with add-visits.phtml
puhlic function addVisitsAction()
{}
```

Comment: I know it's not clear because I don't have the enough information to talk about the problem, any way I am trying to follow the quick start example.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is the crucial part of your question:

```
<?php include_once($this->pageToInclude . ".phtml") ?>
```

Then you can achieve the same using the `render()` method of the view:

```
<?php echo $this->render($this->pageToInclude . ".phtml") ?>
```

You will have to make sure that the .phtml page is in the allowed path for `render()`. If it is just a view script for a regular action in the same controller, it should be in the path already.